# Change x-axis order in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have financial data like this. How can I reorder the x axis in order of AAA, AA+, AA, AA- ....

```
 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(df2, aes( x= as.factor(splticrm), y = z_score)) + 
           geom_boxplot(alpha=0.6, size = 1) + 
           xlab("Rating")
```

[image]

Comment: Try specifying the levels of the factor explicitly. This should order it that way you want `x = as.factor(...)` to `x = factor(splticrm, levels = c("AAA","AA+","AA","AA-"...)`